# Difference between set.upper_bound() and upper_bound(set.begin(), set.end()) stl

Tags: c++, stl

https://codeforces.com/contest/1435/submission/96757666 --> Used set.upper_bound()
https://codeforces.com/contest/1435/submission/96761788 --> Used upper_bound(set.begin(), set.end())

I noticed that set.upper_bound() was faster than the latter (The latter gave Time Limit Exceeded). Why is that?

The code below gives Time Limit Exceeded

> int ind = *upper_bound(st.begin(), st.end(), mp[i], greater< int >());

```
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")
#pragma GCC target("avx,avx2,fma")
#pragma GCC optimization("unroll-loops")
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
# define ll  long long int
# define ld  long double
# define pb push_back
# define pp pop_back
# define ff first
# define ss second
# define mp make_pair
typedef priority_queue<ll, vector<ll>, greater<ll>> minheap;
typedef priority_queue<ll> maxheap;
#define IOS ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

void solve(){
    int n;
      cin>>n;
      set<int, greater<int>>st;
      st.insert(-1);
      map<int,int> mp;
      int p[2*n];
      char s[2*n];
        for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++)
      {
          cin>>s[i];
          if(s[i]=='+')
          st.insert(i);
          else
          {
              cin>>p[i];
              mp[p[i]]=i;
          }
     
      }
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
        
          int ind = *upper_bound(st.begin(), st.end(), mp[i], greater< int>());
          if(ind==-1||st.find(ind)==st.end())
          {
              // if (-) come before +
              cout<<"NO\n";
              return;
          }
          st.erase(ind);
          p[ind] = i;
          
      }
     
    // cout<<endl;
    stack<int>stc;
    for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='+')
        stc.push(p[i]);
        else
        {
            if(stc.top()==p[i])
            stc.pop();
            else
            {
                //if element not in order given in language
                cout<<"NO\n";
                return ;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"YES\n";
    for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='+')
        cout<<p[i]<<endl;
    }
    return;
}   


int  main()
{
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
       freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
       freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif
      IOS
     int t = 1;
     //cin >> t;
     while(t--){
        solve();
     }
    return 0;
}
```

The same code with "set.upper_bound()" get executed within Time Limit.

> int ind = *st.upper_bound(mp[i]);

```
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")
#pragma GCC target("avx,avx2,fma")
#pragma GCC optimization("unroll-loops")
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
# define ll  long long int
# define ld  long double
# define pb push_back
# define pp pop_back
# define ff first
# define ss second
# define mp make_pair
typedef priority_queue<ll, vector<ll>, greater<ll>> minheap;
typedef priority_queue<ll> maxheap;
#define IOS ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

void solve(){
    int n;
      cin>>n;
      set<int, greater<int>>st;
      st.insert(-1);
      map<int,int> mp;
      int p[2*n];
      char s[2*n];
        for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++)
      {
          cin>>s[i];
          if(s[i]=='+')
          st.insert(i);
          else
          {
              cin>>p[i];
              mp[p[i]]=i;
          }
     
      }
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
        
          int ind = *st.upper_bound(mp[i]);
          if(ind==-1||st.find(ind)==st.end())
          {
              // if (-) come before +
              cout<<"NO\n";
              return;
          }
          st.erase(ind);
          p[ind] = i;
          
      }
     
    // cout<<endl;
    stack<int>stc;
    for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='+')
        stc.push(p[i]);
        else
        {
            if(stc.top()==p[i])
            stc.pop();
            else
            {
                //if element not in order given in language
                cout<<"NO\n";
                return ;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"YES\n";
    for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='+')
        cout<<p[i]<<endl;
    }
    return;
}   


int  main()
{
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
       freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
       freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif
      IOS
     int t = 1;
     //cin >> t;
     while(t--){
        solve();
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code directly to StackOverflow.  Links to external sites and break in the future. Having it here as text also allows search engines to index your question for others to find in the future.

Comment: The code is very big, Should I just add only the relevant part or the whole code?

Comment: @BerubolV yes please.

Comment: @J'e The whole code?

Comment: Aside: Why define a macro you only expand once? Combined with the `freopen`s looks suspect. Why not pass a `std::istream` and a `std::ostream` to solve, either `std::cin` and `std::cout` or `std::ifstream("input.txt")` and `std::ofstream("input.txt")`

Comment: I actually copied this format form some other coder so I don't actually know what the macros do. As for freopen("input.txt"), I need this to run the program in Sublime Text Editor

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks I understand now!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry I don't know how to do that. Is there any specific way to do that? I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks I will do it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`set::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/upper_bound) will use the set's capability to search for *value* efficiently (logarithmic with regards to the size of the container).

For [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), using non-`LegacyRandomAccessIterators`, like a `std::set`s iterators (that are `LegacyBidirectionalIterator`s), the number of iterator increments is linear.

Comment: So should we always use "LegacyRandomAccessIterators"? Because on most sites people use upper_bound(set.begin(), set.end()).

Comment: @BeruboIV No, if you have a `std::set` you should use `std::set::upper_bound` and not `std::upper_bound` (since a `std::set` doesn't have `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`s). If you on the other hand have a `std::vector`, then `std::upper_bound` will be efficient.

Comment: @BeruboIV some containers can do some operations more efficiently than the generic algorithms. `std::map::find` vs `std::find` is another example. When a container has a `foo` as member then typically this is prefered over the `std::foo` generic one

Comment: @BeruboIV I made an `upper_bound` function template that uses the proper `upper_bound` function depending on what container you use. Perhaps it can be of use: [`upper_bound`](https://godbolt.org/z/jsjKPh)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Does the function implements Binary Search for all containers?

Comment: @BeruboIV No, that's not possible on containers that can't be sorted, but it will select the member function `upper_bound` if the container has one (which is true for `map`, `set`,  `multimap`, `multiset`, their `pmr` versions and any user defined container having it) and use `std::upper_bound` for the rest. For a container like `vector` it'll do a binary search but for a container like `list` it will not (since a `list` doesn't have `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`s and doing a binary search would be even more inefficent than just looping until the upper bound is found).